# using $scope with this in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
json = [1,2,3]
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.edit = function(){
     $scope.editMode = true;
  };
 
  $scope.data = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <li ng-click="edit()" ng-repeat="d in data">
      {{d}}
      <button ng-show="editMode == true">button</button>
    </li>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

When I click on specified `li`, all of the button showed up, how to show only button that's within a `li`? I know in jquery u have to use `$(this)`, but how about in angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a transcluded element, all the elements inside the `li` share the same scope.

You can have a edit status for each element in the array like

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
json = [1, 2, 3]
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.editMode = [];
  $scope.edit = function(index) {
    $scope.editMode[index] = true;
  };

  $scope.data = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li ng-click="edit($index)" ng-repeat="d in data">
    {{d}}
    <button ng-show="editMode[$index]">button</button>
  </li>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Another option is (if you want to allow to edit only 1 element at a time)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
json = [1, 2, 3]
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.editMode = -1;
  $scope.edit = function(index) {
    $scope.editMode = index;
  };

  $scope.data = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li ng-click="edit($index)" ng-repeat="d in data">
    {{d}}
    <button ng-show="editMode == $index">button</button>
  </li>

</body>

</html>
```